# Type safe service getter class (returning Parameterized Type)

Tags: java, parameterized

What I would like to obtain is something that can safely return the instance of an input class. In my case is used as a service provider. A code sample:

```
 public class MyClass {

    private Map<String, Object> mServices;

    public MyClass() {
        mServices = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        mServices.put(XmlService.class.getName(), new XmlService());
    }

    public <E extends Object> E getService(Class<?> service) {
        return (E) mServices.get(service.getName());
    }
}
```

I admit that I am not that skilled with Parameterized Types and I need some help here. Am I not getting an Object from the Map? Why do I need to cast to E, loosing the type safety?
Is there a way to avoid either casting and/or suppress warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately the is no way to avoid this extra downcast. Notice that the type of your map is `Map<String, Object>`. `Object` - that is all the Java compiler knows about values. You would have to somehow declare the map to have different type of every key. Impossible.

But your code can be simplified a bit:

```
public <E> E getService(Class<E> service) {
    return (E) mServices.get(service.getName());
}
```

Another slight improvement involves using `Class` as key:

```
private Map<Class<?>, Object> mServices;

public <E> E getService(Class<E> service) {
    return (E) mServices.get(service);
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks for the improvements!
What if I put Map<String, ? extends Object> mServices ?
The compiler gives me an error on the put method though.

Comment: @Kap: even if it worked, what would you expect? `Map.get()` would return some class extending `Object` (according to type declaration). You don't need this extra `? extends` to know that.

Answer (score 0):

This should work without the downcast :

```
public class ServiceLoader<T extends AbstractService> {

private Map<String, T> services = new HashMap<String, T>();

T getService(Class<T> componentType) {
    return services.get(componentType.getName());
}
```

Comment: Yes, this will work, but I would need to have one Service class per every type. Right? What I would like to have is a centralized Service getter instead.